# React-Native render after setState does not happen

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, nfc

So I've been working on a React-Native project which involves NFC card reading and for that I am using a library called **react-native nfc manager**. But there is a problem because when it does not re-render after setState.

*setState does not trigger rerender.*

Is that a bug from React-Native?

Comment: Hi, you should share code, error messages and anything you can to help others help you.

To answer your immediate question, no, it is not a bug in react-native

Comment: @dbramwell https://prnt.sc/nm1uoh, https://prnt.sc/nm1uup, https://prnt.sc/nm1wsj. When the user open our page for first time all of code working perfectly and the card save the value. When he goBack or try to add new worker setState doesn't not trigger re render